# How to get path to .ico file from .lnk

Tags: c#, ico, lnk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract Icon from Windows .lnk (shortcut) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343200/extract-icon-from-windows-lnk-shortcut-file)

For example, I have a Shortcut (.LNK) file that has C:\Foo\bar.ico as it's icon. How can I get the path of the icon (C:\Foo\bar.ico) when supplied with just the shortcut file in C#?

I tried using WshShortcut, but WshShortcut.IconLocation only returns a blank string if the icon is an external .ico file. I don't want the index of the icon, just the path of the .ico file.

Comment: I don't want the icon object, I want the string _path_ to the actual .ico or .exe or .dll file itself, where the icon is contained.

Comment: It does provide path, in [the other answer, by Robbie](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13574990/1868397)