# Creating a web shortcut on user desktop programmatically

Tags: windows, shortcut

There are quite a few resources for programmatically creating `.lnk` type shortcuts to files and programs on the desktop but I'm wondering how to create a shortcut to a web URL.

From what I can gather, the web URL shortcut is a text file ending in `.URL` and contains a ini-like definition such as:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.google.com/
```

However, it's not enough to just create the file, it seems you also need to change its meta `URL` properties to include the same link.

Any idea how to create these?

Any sample code from .Net/Perl/batch is welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create .lnk shortcuts to any URI, including web addresses.  Just create the shortcut and make the target your web address instead of a file location.

See this other question for how to do it programmatically:

[Creating application shortcut in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234231/how-do-you-create-an-application-shortcut-lnk-file-in-c-or-net)