# How to create a shortcut that points to default.aspx page from MSI Factory

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-installer, installation

I am using MSIFactory first time to create installer for my web application, I am stuck at following point:

How to create a shortcut that points to default.aspx page of website installed.

I have already worked much on it , I am able to install the web application to local IIS, able to create shortcut on StartMenu.

I read the following link it shows a way , but there is no actual implementation given

http://www.indigorose.com/forums/threads/3550-Shortcut-to-default-browser

Please let me know if you have the exact steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the high-end setup tools (for example Advanced Installer or InstallShield) have direct support for this. Basically, they allow you to create shortcuts to URLs.

If MSIFactory doesn't have this feature, you can create the shortcut manually through [IniFile table](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1026.htm) or by using an [actual INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539962/creating-a-web-shortcut-on-user-desktop-programmatically).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and let you know