# How do I create add a shortcut (.lnk) for my application to the Startup folder programatically in .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-vista, installation, uac

My application will have a per machine (not per user) Startup shortcut.  I can create a shortcut during the installer process no problem.  My problem comes when the user later removes it and then tries to re-enable.  In otherwords, they turn off RunOnStartup (which deletes the Startup ink) and at a later time they decide they do want it to run on startup so they go back into preferences and re-enable.

Apparently, this is a pretty common gripe with .NET that there isn't a native way to create shortcuts.  But, haven't found a very good solution.

Solutions I've Found/Considered:

- Rather then create a shortcut.  Just copy one.  This might be a good solution.  I can't depend on there being a Start Menu link.  But, I guess I could probably create one and keep it in Program Directory... This shifts the problem over to my installer to have to create the shortcut with the appropriate path which would be specified at install time.
- Do what [this other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234231/how-do-you-create-an-application-shortcut-lnk-file-in-c-or-net) is and use a COM wrapper object.  I'd like to avoid COM.  It was also written in 2003.  So, I'm not sure how well it's going to support vista.  I'd give it a shot but don't have a vista box handy.
- Use the registry instead.  This is how I currently do it... but run into issues on Vista.  It seems the general consensus that Startup Menu shortcuts are the proper way to do this so that's what my goal is.

Also, I have to handle the case that a regular user (not an admin) tries to change this preference.  In this case, I need to gracefully fail or in the case of vista allow the user to enter the Admin password to get a Admin security token.  An answer which already properly takes into consider this case would be awesome.

I apologize if this topic has already been covered.  I searched around before posting.

**UPDATE**: Copying a shortcut which your installer created is the best solution.  I'll post code once finished... ran into some hurdles with a) Environment.GetSpecialFolder not having a reference to the StartMenu which has been resolved... But, now i'm dealing with elevating permissions to copy the file to the proper location.  I created a new stackoverflow question for this topic: [How can I copy a file as a "Standard User" in Vista (ie "An Administrative Choice Application") by prompting user for admin credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039875/how-can-i-copy-a-file-as-a-standard-user-in-vista-ie-an-administrative-choice)

Comment: IShellLink works fine in Vista. AFAIK its the best way to create/resolve shortcuts. You can also probably do this with an interop assmbly to IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll but that means you will probably end up shipping an extra interop assembly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested by Joel, the proper solution is to install a shortcut in your program files folder at install time and then copy the .lnk to the startup folder.  Trying to create a shortcut is more difficult.

The code below does the following:

- It gets the path to the All Users Startup Folder for you. Environment.GetSpecialFolder is fairly limited and doesn't have a reference to this folder and as a result you need to make a system call.
- Has methods to copy and remove a shortcut.

Ultimately, I wanted to also make sure that it was gracefully handled on vista if the user running the application was a regular user they would be prompted to enter their credentials.  I created a post here on the subject so check into that here if that's important to you.
[How can I copy a file as a "Standard User" in Vista (ie "An Administrative Choice Application") by prompting user for admin credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039875/how-can-i-copy-a-file-as-a-standard-user-in-vista-ie-an-administrative-choice)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BR.Util
{
public class StartupLinkUtil
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    static extern bool SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner, [Out] StringBuilder lpszPath, int nFolder, bool fCreate);

    public static string getAllUsersStartupFolder()
    {
        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(200);
        SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, path, CSIDL_COMMON_STARTUP, false);
        return path.ToString();
    }


    private static string getStartupShortcutFilename()
    {
        return Path.Combine(getAllUsersStartupFolder(), Application.ProductName) + ".lnk";
    }

   public static bool CopyShortcutToAllUsersStartupFolder(string pShortcutName)
    {
        bool retVal = false;
        FileInfo shortcutFile = new FileInfo(pShortcutName);
        FileInfo destination = new FileInfo(getStartupShortcutFilename());

        if (destination.Exists)
        {
            // Don't do anything file already exists.  -- Potentially overwrite?
        }
        else if (!shortcutFile.Exists)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to RunOnStartup because '" + pShortcutName + "' can't be found.  Was this application installed properly?");
        }
        else
        {
            retVal = copyFile(shortcutFile, destination);
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public static bool doesShortcutExistInAllUsersStartupFolder()
    {
        return File.Exists(getStartupShortcutFilename());
    }

    public static bool RemoveShortcutFromAllUsersStartupFolder() {
        bool retVal = false;
        string path = Path.Combine(getAllUsersStartupFolder(), Application.ProductName) + ".lnk";
        if( File.Exists(path) ) {
            try
            {
                File.Delete(path);
                retVal = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Unable to remove this application from the Startup list.  Administrative privledges are required to perform this operation.\n\nDetails: SecurityException: {0}", ex.Message), "Update Startup Mode", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    // TODO: Test this in vista to see if it prompts for credentials.
    public static bool copyFile(FileInfo pSource, FileInfo pDestination)
    {
        bool retVal = false;

        try
        {
            File.Copy(pSource.FullName, pDestination.FullName);
            //MessageBox.Show("File has successfully been added.", "Copy File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            retVal = true;
        }
        catch (System.Security.SecurityException secEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("SecurityException: {0}", secEx.Message), "Copy File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException authEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("UnauthorizedAccessException: {0}", authEx.Message), "Copy File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Copy File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    #region Special Folder constants
    const int CSIDL_DESKTOP = 0x0000;        // <desktop>
    const int CSIDL_INTERNET = 0x0001;        // Internet Explorer (icon on desktop)
    const int CSIDL_PROGRAMS = 0x0002;        // Start Menu\Programs
    const int CSIDL_CONTROLS = 0x0003;        // My Computer\Control Panel
    const int CSIDL_PRINTERS = 0x0004;        // My Computer\Printers
    const int CSIDL_PERSONAL = 0x0005;        // My Documents
    const int CSIDL_FAVORITES = 0x0006;        // <user name>\Favorites
    const int CSIDL_STARTUP = 0x0007;        // Start Menu\Programs\Startup
    const int CSIDL_RECENT = 0x0008;        // <user name>\Recent
    const int CSIDL_SENDTO = 0x0009;        // <user name>\SendTo
    const int CSIDL_BITBUCKET = 0x000a;        // <desktop>\Recycle Bin
    const int CSIDL_STARTMENU = 0x000b;        // <user name>\Start Menu
    const int CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS = CSIDL_PERSONAL; //  Personal was just a silly name for My Documents
    const int CSIDL_MYMUSIC = 0x000d;        // "My Music" folder
    const int CSIDL_MYVIDEO = 0x000e;        // "My Videos" folder
    const int CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY = 0x0010;        // <user name>\Desktop
    const int CSIDL_DRIVES = 0x0011;        // My Computer
    const int CSIDL_NETWORK = 0x0012;        // Network Neighborhood (My Network Places)
    const int CSIDL_NETHOOD = 0x0013;        // <user name>\nethood
    const int CSIDL_FONTS = 0x0014;        // windows\fonts
    const int CSIDL_TEMPLATES = 0x0015;
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_STARTMENU = 0x0016;        // All Users\Start Menu
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS = 0x0017;        // All Users\Start Menu\Programs
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_STARTUP = 0x0018;        // All Users\Startup
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY = 0x0019;        // All Users\Desktop
    const int CSIDL_APPDATA = 0x001a;        // <user name>\Application Data
    const int CSIDL_PRINTHOOD = 0x001b;        // <user name>\PrintHood
    const int CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA = 0x001c;        // <user name>\Local Settings\Applicaiton Data (non roaming)
    const int CSIDL_ALTSTARTUP = 0x001d;        // non localized startup
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_ALTSTARTUP = 0x001e;        // non localized common startup
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_FAVORITES = 0x001f;
    const int CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE = 0x0020;
    const int CSIDL_COOKIES = 0x0021;
    const int CSIDL_HISTORY = 0x0022;
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA = 0x0023;        // All Users\Application Data
    const int CSIDL_WINDOWS = 0x0024;        // GetWindowsDirectory()
    const int CSIDL_SYSTEM = 0x0025;        // GetSystemDirectory()
    const int CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES = 0x0026;        // C:\Program Files
    const int CSIDL_MYPICTURES = 0x0027;        // C:\Program Files\My Pictures
    const int CSIDL_PROFILE = 0x0028;        // USERPROFILE
    const int CSIDL_SYSTEMX86 = 0x0029;        // x86 system directory on RISC
    const int CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86 = 0x002a;        // x86 C:\Program Files on RISC
    const int CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES_COMMON = 0x002b;        // C:\Program Files\Common
    const int CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES_COMMONX86 = 0x002c;        // x86 Program Files\Common on RISC
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_TEMPLATES = 0x002d;        // All Users\Templates
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS = 0x002e;        // All Users\Documents
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_ADMINTOOLS = 0x002f;        // All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
    const int CSIDL_ADMINTOOLS = 0x0030;        // <user name>\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
    const int CSIDL_CONNECTIONS = 0x0031;        // Network and Dial-up Connections
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_MUSIC = 0x0035;        // All Users\My Music
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_PICTURES = 0x0036;        // All Users\My Pictures
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_VIDEO = 0x0037;        // All Users\My Video
    const int CSIDL_RESOURCES = 0x0038;        // Resource Direcotry
    const int CSIDL_RESOURCES_LOCALIZED = 0x0039;        // Localized Resource Direcotry
    const int CSIDL_COMMON_OEM_LINKS = 0x003a;        // Links to All Users OEM specific apps
    const int CSIDL_CDBURN_AREA = 0x003b;        // USERPROFILE\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\CD Burning
    const int CSIDL_COMPUTERSNEARME = 0x003d;        // Computers Near Me (computered from Workgroup membership)
    const int CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE = 0x8000;        // combine with CSIDL_ value to force folder creation in SHGetFolderPath()
    const int CSIDL_FLAG_DONT_VERIFY = 0x4000;        // combine with CSIDL_ value to return an unverified folder path
    const int CSIDL_FLAG_DONT_UNEXPAND = 0x2000;        // combine with CSIDL_ value to avoid unexpanding environment variables
    const int CSIDL_FLAG_NO_ALIAS = 0x1000;        // combine with CSIDL_ value to insure non-alias versions of the pidl
    const int CSIDL_FLAG_PER_USER_INIT = 0x0800;        // combine with CSIDL_ value to indicate per-user init (eg. upgrade)
    #endregion
}
```

While I was  writing this solution, I thought of a better way of handling the problem which wouldn't require users to have escalated privledges in order to disable run on startup.
My solution was to check as soon as the program loaded if a user scoped setting called RunOnStartup.  To detect if the application was being started when the system loads or logs in I added an argument to the shortcut which gets added to the All Users -> Startup folder called shortcut.

```
        // Quit the application if the per user setting for RunOnStartup is false.
            if (args != null && args.Length > 0 && args[0].Contains("startup"))
            {
                if (Settings1.Default.RunOnStartup == false)
                {
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I combined this solution with [How can Windows file and folder shortcuts be created via C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11513681/3090544)

Answer (score 3):

You can install a shortcut to your app in it's program files folder, and then just copy that .lnk file as needed.

Answer (score 3):

i got it done with this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Shell32;
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;
using System.IO;

namespace CMS.data
{
    public class overall
    {
        public static void place_shortcut_on_desktop()
        {
            string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\YourName.lnk";
            string shortcutto = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

            var wsh = new IWshShell_Class();
            IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = wsh.CreateShortcut(desktopPath) as IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut;
            shortcut.TargetPath = shortcutto;
            shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetParent(shortcutto).FullName;
            shortcut.Save();
        }
    }//class overall
}
```

Remember the "Working Directory" it might make problems otherwise

you could also add the icon this way but in my case i didn't need it

its my first answer here at stack overflow so a thanks would really help

Comment: Thank you so much, seeing this in 2017, still helpful

Answer (score -1):

I've been using this solution for a while now and seems to work nicely.

[ShellLink](http://www.msjogren.net/dotnet/eng/samples/dotnet_shelllink.asp)