# Programmatically create shortcuts for folders in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

I have a folder A and a folder B. For each subfolder inside A I need to check if B contains a link to that subfolder. If not, I need to create it.

I'm currently creating the links using the code found on this page: [Creating a file shortcut (.lnk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023379/creating-a-file-shortcut-lnk)
My problem is that this code always creates a file shortcut, not a folder shortcut, so if I try to open the shortcut it does not open the corresponding folder. Anyone knows how to create folder shortcuts instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question because I found lots of people asking this on the web and nobody providing an answer.

I found through trial and error that if you use the `Path.GetFullPath` method to calculate the value to assign to the `TargetPath` property, the output is in a format that's recognized as a folder path, so the system will automatically identify it as a folder shortcut and assign the corresponding icon.

Answer (score -1):

FileSelectFolder, directory
if (directory != ""){
Loop, %directory%*.*, 1, 1
{
if (FileExist(A_LoopFileFullPath) = "D")
FileCreateDir, % A_Desktop "\myShortcuts" SubStr(A_LoopFileFullPath, StrLen(directory) + 1)
else
FileCreateShortcut, %A_LoopFileFullPath%, % A_Desktop "\myShortcuts" SubStr(A_LoopFileFullPath, StrLen(directory) + 1) A_LoopFileName ".lnk"
}
Run, % A_Desktop "\myShortcuts"
}
Esc::ExitApp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).