# Automatic create shortcut in one folder, pointing to another folder with the same name

Tags: windows, shortcut

I'm running a Windows Server 2016 with folder shares. On one of the shares I have the folder Customers, containing one folder per customer. On another share I have a folder called Archive. In this folder I have one folder per customer archive, sharing the same name.

What I'd like is to create a shortcut in each customer folder linking to the customer archive folder:

Customer A > Archive\Customer A
Customer B > Archive\Customer B

It's easy to do this manually - just create a shortcut pointing to the archive folder, but since I have close to 1000 folders, I'd like to do this automatically somehow.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

/Carl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically create shortcuts for folders in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429067/programmatically-create-shortcuts-for-folders-in-windows)

Comment: Sorry, that didn't really help.

Comment: Dig through to [the source question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023379/creating-a-file-shortcut-lnk) for code.