# Windows Shortcuts Created Programmatically Don't Work

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, shortcut

I've used C# and Powershell to create shortcuts, but when they are created in code they do not work. I click on the shortcut, the cursor shows the PC is thinking for a second and then nothing happens. This is the Powershell code I was using:

```
$currPath = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$tgtPath = ($currPath + "\bin\MyApp.exe")
$scutPath = ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\MyApp.lnk")
$wShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$scut = $wShell.CreateShortcut($scutPath)
$scut.TargetPath = $tgtPath
$scut.Save()
```

The C# code does essentially the same think using the IWshRuntimeLibrary. This little script basically just creates a shortcut on someone's desktop after they have downloaded my little standalone executable. I can manually create the shortcut and everything works fine. Why can't I do it through code?

I have created a few shortcuts and .url files on the desktop with the same name in the course of my testing, I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: Right click the shortcut made programmatically and compare the "Target" and "Start In" fields to your manually made one that works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a file shortcut (.lnk)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023379/creating-a-file-shortcut-lnk)

Comment: Try the solution provided in the above link. (and keep in mind the note regarding .NET 4.0 reference of `WshShell` vs `WshShellClass`.  The solution is for c#.

Comment: @Quantic - That is exactly right. I did compare the properties carefully before, but I overlooked the start in field. Put this as the answer and I can accept it. The property that needs to be set is the WorkingDirectory of the shortcut object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You often have to ensure the [`WorkingDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ae0a4aee(v=vs.84).aspx) is assigned or else your program's `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will inherit the directory you called the shortcut from. Your program is likely closing due to not finding a resource by using a relative path, such as an icon: `_notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"Resources\Icons\myicon.ico");` will crash when using a shortcut with a blank `WorkingDirectory` when the shortcut is launched from a process with a different working directory than where your .exe resides (e.g., the Explorer process that reads your shortcut and launches your program when you double click a shortcut).

You can test what a relative path expands to by using `Path.GetFullPath(string relativePath)`, and you can see the current directory with `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. Launching a shortcut from the desktop with no Start In set I see the working directory as my desktop, meaning `@"Resources\Icons\myicon.ico"` will be expanded to `@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Resources\Icons\myicon.ico` which is no good as the icon is somewhere else like `@"C:\Program Files\MyProgram\Resources\Icons\myicon.ico"`.