# How to open Create Shortcut Wizard

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, windows-8.1

I want to use the windows Create Shortcut Wizard to create the short cut from my C# (WinForm) application.

I want to give the target location to Wizard to save the .lnk file.

[image]

Comment: if you want to create shortcut only then you can create ir dynamicallty from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501608/how-do-you-create-an-application-shortcut-lnk-file-in-c-sharp-with-command-li/1501727#1501727

Comment: @GujjuDeveloper  : Yeah I can below is the code spinet I have implemented but we client requirement to use the Create Shortcut Wizard.
here is the code ---->





 public void CreateShortcut(string file, string shortcurName)
    {
      WshShellClass wshShell= new WshShellClass();
      IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut) wshShell.CreateShortcut(FAVOURITES + shortcurName.Trim() + SHORTCUT_EXTENSION);
      shortcut.TargetPath = file;
      shortcut.Save();
    }

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234231/creating-application-shortcut-in-a-directory

Comment: @NullReference : The functionality using code is already in-place, but want to use 'Create Shortcut Wizard', so user can get the families windows UI interface.