# How to create a relative Windows shortcut in C#?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to combine two questions here: 1) [How to create a relative shortcut in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169556/making-a-windows-shortcut-start-relative-to-where-the-folder-is) and 2) [How to create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501608/how-do-you-create-an-application-shortcut-lnk-file-in-c-sharp-with-command-li/1501727#1501727) [a Windows shortcut in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897655/create-shortcut-on-desktop-c-sharp)

I have the following code to create shortcuts (based on the questions I've seen), but it throws an exception when assigning `shortcut.TargetPath`: "Value does not fall within the expected range"

```
public void CreateShortcut() {
    IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell wsh = new IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell();
    IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = wsh.CreateShortcut(Path.Combine(outputFolder, "sc.lnk")) as IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut;
    shortcut.Arguments = "";
    shortcut.TargetPath = "%windir%\\system32\\cmd.exe /c start \"\" \"%CD%\\folder\\executable.exe\"";
    shortcut.WindowStyle = 1;
    shortcut.Description = "executable";
    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "%CD%";
    shortcut.IconLocation = "";
    shortcut.Save();
}
```

How do I fix this and create my relative shortcut?

NB: I don't want to have to write a batch script to do this as my software will most likely be installed on PCs where the user does not have access to a command line - our clients often have very locked-down machines and will almost certainly not have the right permissions to run batch files. If you do have any suggestions as to how I might create a 'portable' folder (with my .exe in a subfolder) where the user only has to double-click something in the top level folder to run the exe, I am open to suggestions!

Comment: Can't that "something" be an executable?

Comment: It can, but that was a last resort. I was hoping to make the whole 'package' as light and bulk-free as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put arguments in the `TargetPath`-property. (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/594k4c67%28v=vs.84%29.aspx))

Put them into the `Arguments`- property:

```
public void CreateShortcut() {
    IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell wsh = new IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell();
    IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = wsh.CreateShortcut(Path.Combine(outputFolder, "sc.lnk")) as IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut;
    shortcut.Arguments = "/c start \"\" \"%CD%\\folder\\executable.exe\"";
    shortcut.TargetPath = "%windir%\\system32\\cmd.exe";
    shortcut.WindowStyle = 1;
    shortcut.Description = "executable";
    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "%CD%";
    shortcut.IconLocation = "P:\ath\to\any\icon.ico";
    shortcut.Save();
}
```