# Get lnk shortcut target from public (all users) folder without elevating admin privileges

Tags: c#, .net, windows, shortcut

I am looking for a way to read lnk shortcut target, when this one locates in public folder such as:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

I tried to use following:

1. Interop.Shell32.FolderItem.GetLink - it throws an exception ( [Why do i get E_ACCESSDENIED when reading public shortcuts through Shell32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934420/why-do-i-get-e-accessdenied-when-reading-public-shortcuts-through-shell32) )
2. IWshShortcut https://stackoverflow.com/a/13079688/1722921 - it throws an exception too (from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))

And I didn't find others ways to do this.
I know that I can fix it with elevating admin rights for my program, but I don't want to do it, since I can easily read the values through the Windows UI without getting an elevation prompt. So I am looking for a way programmatically read shortcut target without admin privileges.

Comment: Have you tried to copy the shortcut to temporary folder and read it from here?

Comment: @MCND Of course such circumvention works. But I am looking for more reasonable way :) I read many shortcuts (not one) so it will be much longer time, if I will copy each shortcut, that for my task is not quite acceptable.

Comment: No need to copy all links. Handle the exception and do it only for the "problematic" links.

Comment: @MCND There are many such "problematic" links...