# Creating a shortcut to a folder in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

To make a long story short, I need to to create a shortcut to a folder using C#. I've been reading on using `IWshRuntimeLibrary`. When I go to try anything using `IWshRuntimeLibrary` I get all sorts of ambiguity errors with `System.IO.File`. I'm assuming this is because there is a `IWshRuntimeLibrary.File` interface along with `System.IO.File`. All I've really been able to find are articles on making shortcuts to apps, not folders.

Ambiguity Errors aside:

- Is this the right tool to use for folder shortcuts?
- How do I create a shortcut using this
- How do I specify where the shortcut is placed

Also when I try to create a shortcut to a folder, say `C:\TEMP` using this:

```
IWshShortcut shortcut;
wshShell = new WshShellClass();
shortcut = (IWshShortcut)wshShell.CreateShortcut(@"C:\TEMP");

shortcut.TargetPath = @"C:\Documents and Settings";
```

I get a `COMException`. According to what I've read this should create a shortcut to the C drive temp folder and put the shortcut in the Documents and Settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391923/placing-a-shortcut-in-users-startup-folder-to-start-with-windows

Comment: To get rid of your ambiguity errors, make sure when you want to use the .NET File class, you call System.IO.File, and use IWShRuntimeLibrary.File when using the other. This problem happens to me all the time if I want to use a Timer in a class that both uses System.Windows.Forms and System.Threading, because they both contain a Timer class. Sorry I cannot help with your main problem.

Comment: @ademing2, I kinda figured that's what I would have to do, but before adding that before all my System.IO.File method calls I wanted to see if I was on the right track. Thanks though

Comment: @Desolator: no, this is a duplicate of a different question, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897655/create-shortcut-on-desktop-c-sharp). :)

Comment: maybe you can use an [alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to help you disambiguate System.IO.File without specifying the full namespace every time

Comment: Not an exe shortcut, but a shortcut to a folder...unless that's the same thing, which would answer my question then. Kinda like how you can make a shortcut to a folder on a network pc is what I'm aiming for here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dont forget to set Embed Interop Types to False to reference Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.
I tested and works without getting an error.

```
  // Make sure you use try/catch block because your App may has no permissions on the target path!
  try
  {
    CreateShortcut(@"C:\temp", @"C:\MyShortcutFile.lnk",
        "Custom Shortcut", "/param", "Ctrl+F", @"c:\");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }



   /// <summary>
    /// Create Windows Shorcut
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="SourceFile">A file you want to make shortcut to</param>
    /// <param name="ShortcutFile">Path and shorcut file name including file extension (.lnk)</param>
    public static void CreateShortcut(string SourceFile, string ShortcutFile)
    {
      CreateShortcut(SourceFile, ShortcutFile, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create Windows Shorcut
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="SourceFile">A file you want to make shortcut to</param>
    /// <param name="ShortcutFile">Path and shorcut file name including file extension (.lnk)</param>
    /// <param name="Description">Shortcut description</param>
    /// <param name="Arguments">Command line arguments</param>
    /// <param name="HotKey">Shortcut hot key as a string, for example "Ctrl+F"</param>
    /// <param name="WorkingDirectory">"Start in" shorcut parameter</param>
    public static void CreateShortcut(string TargetPath, string ShortcutFile, string Description,
       string Arguments, string HotKey, string WorkingDirectory)
    {
      // Check necessary parameters first:
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TargetPath))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("TargetPath");
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ShortcutFile))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("ShortcutFile");

      // Create WshShellClass instance:
      var wshShell = new WshShellClass();

      // Create shortcut object:
      IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shorcut = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)wshShell.CreateShortcut(ShortcutFile);

      // Assign shortcut properties:
      shorcut.TargetPath = TargetPath;
      shorcut.Description = Description;
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Arguments))
        shorcut.Arguments = Arguments;
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HotKey))
        shorcut.Hotkey = HotKey;
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(WorkingDirectory))
        shorcut.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory;

      // Save the shortcut:
      shorcut.Save();
    }
```

source: [http://zayko.net/post/How-to-create-Windows-shortcut-(C).aspx](http://zayko.net/post/How-to-create-Windows-shortcut-%28C%29.aspx)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I was getting close to this solution as well. Just wasn't naming my .lnk for the shortcut file properly

Comment: Source link is no longer valid as it has been archived. Here is the new link: [How-to-create-Windows-shortcut-(C)](http://zayko.net/post/How-to-create-Windows-shortcut-(C))

Answer (score 4):

You got it the other way around: you're trying to make `C:\Temp` a shortcut to your `C:\Documents and Settings` folder.

The following snippet will create a shortcut to a network folder on your desktop:

```
var desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
IWshShortcut shortcut;
var wshShell = new WshShellClass();
shortcut = (IWshShortcut)wshShell.CreateShortcut(Path.Combine(desktop, @"Temp.lnk"));
shortcut.TargetPath = @"\\computername\sharename";
shortcut.Save();
```

Comment: I realize it's been forever, but I'm trying to use this method to create a link to a folder named something like 2.7.1, and when I try to click on the resulting shortcut, Windows tries to open the folder like a file. Any thoughts on how to make sure Windows knows this is a shortcut to a folder?

Answer (score -1):

A solution that is using `IShellLink` on experts-exchange:

[Creating Shortcuts in .NET](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/A_3664-Creating-Shortcuts-in-NET.html)

Provides a managed layer for you to create File and Folder shorcuts.

It is VB.NET, but you can convert it to C# using free converters.

Comment: Downvoters - I understand the link is expired now, 6 years after the answer was posted, making my answer less useful. However, this is not your typical link only answer, which deserves a downvote.