# Create a application shortcut

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you create an application shortcut (.lnk file) in C# or .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234231/how-do-you-create-an-application-shortcut-lnk-file-in-c-or-net)

I guys I needed a help on how to create a application shortcut programmaticaly  in c#

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

http://vbaccelerator.com/article.asp?id=4301

```
  private static void configStep_addShortcutToStartupGroup()
    {
            using (ShellLink shortcut = new ShellLink())
            {
                    shortcut.Target = Application.ExecutablePath;
                    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
                    shortcut.Description = "My Shorcut Name Here";
                    shortcut.DisplayMode = ShellLink.LinkDisplayMode.edmNormal;
                    shortcut.Save(
                            STARTUP_SHORTCUT_FILEPATH);
            }
    }
```

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/shelllink.aspx) is a CodeProject example on the same topic.