# Can not copy files to Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, system, startup, directory

To make my application to start on Windows sturup I decided to put a shortcut to Startup folder.

I tried to use:

```
File.Move(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ApplicationName.exe", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup) + "ApplicationName.lnk");
```

It works, but it moves my shortcut not to the folder I need.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)
```

works well, it returns:

```
C:\Users\Germanov\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

But my shortcut appears in

```
C:\Users\Germanov\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Just 1 folder "behind".

```
File.Delete(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup) + "ApplicationName.lnk");
```

also works "strange". It actually deletes this file, but again not in "Startup" folder.

If I try to manually add "\Startup" to the path like this:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup) + @"Startup\ApplicationName.lnk"
```

I get a System.IO.Excseption.

I can't type this path manually, I neen my application to work at diferent PCs with different versions of Windows. I also can't use Registry to make my application start with windows startup.

I use Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0, this is a WPF project.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the code your using to create the shortcut please.

Comment: I took it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234231/creating-application-shortcut-in-a-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartup instead of Startup, I don't know why startup is not working for your requirement. Most of installer package do this for you; why do you want to do this for your self? Any reason not for using Registry?

I tried this code on my machine

```
var startup = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartup);
string file = Path.Combine(startup, "MyApp.lnk");
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
{
sw.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

And its coming on my startup

[image]

Comment: CommonStartup has the same problem. It copies file to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs.

Comment: CommonStartup has the same problem. It copies file to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs. I want to do this manually to give users opportunity to switch off and on this function. I dont want to use Registry because accses to it may be blocked on different users.

Comment: Look my Startup folder in Start menu

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code works well. I used File.Copy() instead of using StreamWriter, and file appers in correct folder. I think it is about Path.Combine(), but I don't understand how it works. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome. Make it an answer :)

Comment: "Any reason not for using Registry?" WTF? Why on earth would you trawl through the Registry when there's a *documented, supported* API for doing exactly what you want? (A with less code?)

Answer (score 2):

You should use System.IO.Path.Combine() so that you won't create StartupApplication1.exe.  Note the missing backslash.