# Run unity player exe at windows startup automatically

Tags: unity-game-engine

As i have only unity build in exe format how can i put it to the startup of my window so that it run automatically when computer becomes start. Remember I don't want to put it manually is there any scripting ref available to do this or else auto solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to put it manually" ? It's the best way that you add the exe in Start up

Comment: @Sachin actually user dont know how to put the application on startup so that i want to put my exe on startup automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your application to startup with registry 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14280290/6720987

You can also place it in the windows startup folder

```
   string startupFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
        if (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() != startupFolder)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(startupFolder, "MyFile.exe");
            string ownPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Delete(path);
            }
            File.Copy(ownPath, path);
        }
```

Beware that almost every virus scanner with see this as malicious

Comment: you could place it in your main

Comment: I have now experience with unity. But you should place it in a function that runs on start

Comment: ok i got your meaning but is their any way available to exe name also so that i can put it automatically.

Comment: how do i folder also at there? because it is mandatory to add folder with exe

Comment: if the exe is open and i run this code then it is not fully copy the exe. So what to do if exe is open and you want to copy

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 you can do this:

```
FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory("unityProject/mygame.exe", "%userprofile%/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup/mygame.exe" );
```

Comment: This will also copy when already in startup folder, Causing an exeption

Comment: @CodeJoy true, you have to check for overwrite first

Answer (score 0):

I want to give my end user an elegant and efficient way to add my exe to Windows startup and here i have managed to provide him batch file in the directory of my exe.

```
@echo off
Rem This Summary: This batch script will use to add current directories exe file into windows startup folder.
Rem It will work as follow
Rem 1. First search the exe file in the parent directory of this batch file (only one exe should be available next to batch file)
Rem 2. Make its shortcut
Rem 3. paste in sLinkFile(variable name of the location)

set "SCRIPT=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

::Retriving full path of the .exe which is located in the parent directoy of the batch file(next to batch file)
for %%F in ("%~dp0*.exe") do set "EXEFILE=%%~fF"

> "%SCRIPT%" (
    echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)

    Rem Getting the startup path of the current user
    echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Player.lnk"

    Rem creating shortcut
    echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut^(sLinkFile^)

    Rem target path alread extracted in line 11
    echo oLink.TargetPath = "%EXEFILE%"

    Rem save the shortcut
    echo oLink.Save
)

cscript //NoLogo "%SCRIPT%"
del "%SCRIPT%"
```

This file will be placed next to my player build and as user will run this batch file a shortcut of my exe will create automatically and added to the startup. So there is no manual work require just a batch file has to run.