# How to add application icon?

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-installer

In my solution I have WinForms application called JCommander and JCommanderSetupProject.
In JCommander Resources folder i have an icon file i want to be placed on Desktop and Start Menu.

How i do that?

Comment: I hope you are asking the wrong question. You mean you want a *shortcut* in those places, not an *icon*, right?

Comment: Yes, i mean shortcut with desired icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've said, I think you're talking about an application shortcut, which is the icon you normally find on your desktop, start menu or quick-start bar, if I'm mistaken please tell me.

There's some responses at [Creating application shortcut in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234231/creating-application-shortcut-in-a-directory) which answer your question.

The main answer is to use [ShellLink.cs](http://vbaccelerator.com/article.asp?id=4301), which takes care of everything for you after you give it whatever parameters it needs. (You might need to import it into a separate project and edit some parts).

Example:

```
private static void configStep_addShortcutToStartupGroup()
{
    using (ShellLink shortcut = new ShellLink())
    {
        shortcut.Target = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        shortcut.Description = "Shortcut To My Application";
        shortcut.DisplayMode = ShellLink.LinkDisplayMode.edmNormal;
        shortcut.IconPath = "/Path/to/icon.ico";
        shortcut.Save(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop + @"\My Shortcut.lnk");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your project, click the project menu, and select project properties. Then, under the application tab, there is a place to browse for your icon. you can create action on your setup project to create short cut for the application.