# How to edit path in a Windows link file

Tags: c#

I want to edit the path in a link file which leeds to a file or folder which changes it's path quite often. I found some things in C or other languages but never for C#.

Test.lnk -> `C:\TestFolder 1.2.3\`
I want to change that link using C# to
Test.lnk -> `C:\TestFolder 1.2.4\`

Does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: Check out the top answer for the following question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234231/creating-application-shortcut-in-a-directory.

Comment: Is there nothing native? Furthermore I need something also working on WinXP. They only tried Win Server 2008 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to edit the path in a link file. Instead you can delete the old shortcut and create a new one using the COM Windows Script Host Object Model:

```
using System;
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;

namespace ShortCutTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var wsh = new WshShell();
            var shortcut = (IWshShortcut)wsh.CreateShortcut(@"C:\cmd.lnk");
            shortcut.Description = "Shortcut for cmd.exe";
            shortcut.TargetPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) +  @"\cmd.exe";
            shortcut.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know there is no native way in .NET to do that.