# Change desktop icon in code

Tags: c#, icons, shortcut

Hi how can I change the icon of a desktop shortcut via code? Im really puzzled. I have tried getting the icon of the shortcut with 
 `Icon iocn = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);` but then I don't know how to replace the current icon with a new one...Please help

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/ce3ba993-2578-48b5-acb4-5421af950b05 I used as reference and just tweaked it a bit...this worked fine for what I intended Thanx for everyones input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to recreate the shortcut from scratch. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234231/creating-application-shortcut-in-a-directory) for several different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Using [ShellLink Class](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Shell_Projects/Creating_and_Modifying_Shortcuts/article.asp) you can modify the shortcuts