# How can I place a Desktop App shortcut on the Windows 8 Start screen without using an installer?

Tags: c#, windows-8

My Desktop Application is just a single exe file. For reasons that aren't important, I can't use an installer which would add an icon to the Windows 8 Start screen. Can one be added programatically with C#?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about Windows 8, but previous versions of windows simply had a folder for shortcuts.  In Windows 7, this is C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu (for all users).

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work with Windows 8.

Answer (score 4):

If you right click on the exe you can click pin-to start
[image: Pin to start]

This worked for my example in the image, which is a stand-alone exe without any sort of installation.  It will then appear on the start bar.[image]

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:  I realized after that you said programmatically.
It looks like a link to the start page is put in C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs [image]
So perhaps you could tell it to deposit a short cut there?

**EDIT 2**   this previous question may also be helpful: [Creating application shortcut in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234231/creating-application-shortcut-in-a-directory).  It is in C#

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [code samples for enabling desktop notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802762%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a prerequisite of which is the existence of a shortcut installed to the Start screen. The sample is C++ w/COM, but you should be able to incorporate this small bit into a C# app (or rewrite the sample code in C# directly).