# Run vb.net app at startup

Tags: .net, vb.net, startup, regedit

I'm a beginner in vb.net, and I stuck at setting my app to the startup register, I googled en found a lot of different code's but NO one would work for me so far!

This one (I found him during searching on stackoverflow) isn't compatible with vb.net, you need permissions (license) to do this:

```
   Imports Microsoft.Win32
   Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim regStartUp As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)

    Dim value As String

    value = regStartUp.GetValue("Myapp")

    If value <> Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() Then

        regStartUp.CreateSubKey("Myapp")
        regStartUp.SetValue("Myapp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString())

    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

So I tried this:

```
   Dim CU As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = _
Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey _
("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run")
    With CU
.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\ _CurrentVersion\Run", True)
        .SetValue("login.exe", "C:\Users\evert\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\login\login\bin\Debug\")
    End With
```

Won't work neither because when I look into my regedit it does not show up?

I need a answer on this, my friends couldn't help me :( 
I hope you guys can help me! Best regards me!

Comment: just place a short cut to your app in the user's startup on their start menu

Comment: But then you start it by you're self!

Comment: No, Windows launches whatever is in the StartUp folder/hive when windows starts.  The reason it exists is to get away from registry bloat and permission issues writing to certain hives.

Comment: Can you give me the folder? I don't know if it exists? (I mean the location)

Comment: use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)` each user has their own.  be sure to create a shortcut to store there not the actual EXE...see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234231/creating-application-shortcut-in-a-directory

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the app need to run as administrator (or UAC is causing the problem) to edit the registry and
2. I use

   ```
   Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
   regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)
   regKey.SetValue(Application.ProductName, """" & Application.ExecutablePath & """")
   regKey.Close()
   ```

I think it's almost the same?