# How to Create Desktop Shortcut in c#.net application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have created a desktop shortcut from Visual studio 2010 and it was created successfully but when I right-click on it for 'open file location' it open the desktop path where shortcut is created . but I want to open application start up path.

Please help!

Comment: Nothing related to programming right? SO is or programming related questions. You may ask your question is SuperUser.

Comment: Yes It is . because , It can be created programmatically also .

Comment: Something that can be achieved programmatically not necessarily makes it a programming question. If your question is about programming, what you have already tried, and what doesn't work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating application shortcut in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234231/creating-application-shortcut-in-a-directory)

Comment: Consider marking the reply below as the correct answer.

Comment: @PravinWadichar put your code

Comment: Please understand my problem , I will write it down once again with steps
1) I have created an application with its desktop shortcut from Visual Studio Installer.
2) Desktop Shortcut Created successfully.
3)Now , as I right click on this shortcut for open file location , It reaches to Desktop Path (means it shows me this shortcut path)
4)As If we click on any desktop shortcut for open file location it shows its directory path I want the same .
So how to do this

Answer (score 1):

Click right-mousebutton, then properties and inspect the "Start in" property in the Shortcut tab. This should give you the path to the application.

Comment: I can't understand what you want to say ?

Comment: right mouseclick on the icon. Go to properties. Go to Shortcut tab. Check the "Start in" property.

Comment: When I created desktop shortcut from Visual Studio 2010 it created but when I right click on it "Open File Location" and Click for it , this shortcut shows me desktop path not the actual file location of its execution path.

Comment: That's why you don't press open file location but you check the Start in. Otherwise make the shortcut manually, should work too.

Comment: I press it , I don't want to create it manually . Please Help!

Comment: Consider posting this question on https://superuser.com - they may be able to help you there.