# Resolving of shell links in c# under Windows 7 fails

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-shell

I try to resolve the paths of shell links, which are contained in the "Recent Documents" folder in Windows 7. I used the code posted here (Answer No 3) [How to resolve a .lnk in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139010/how-to-resolve-a-lnk-in-c). But the method `ResolveShortcut` is not able to determine the path of some files (e.g. many .txt-files). The same code works perfectly under Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded, upgraded to 2010 and ran [this](http://www.msjogren.net/dotnet/eng/samples/dotnet_shelllink.asp) sample on a Win7 system without any problem without changing anything whatsoever.

Comment: I noticed that one needs to run the code in a WinForms or WPF app. So that was the reason that my code did not work.