# .NET read binary contents of .lnk file

Tags: c#, .net, shortcut

I want to read the binary contents of a .lnk file.
As long as the target of the shortcut (lnk file) exists this works fine with IO.File.ReadAllBytes(string file).

BUT

If the target of the shortcut does not exist (believe me I want this) the method only returns zero's. I guess this is because the OS follows the link and if it does not exist it returns zero's

Is there some way to bypass the fact that the framework follows the target of the .lnk before displaying the contents of the .lnk file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the file was locked because it was copied from another machine (i'm using server 2008 r2) unlocking it returned the behavoir to expected.

Stupid me.

Answer (score 25):

It doesn't make a lot of sense, don't have an easy way to check it.  I reckon the best approach is to read the .lnk file the way it is supposed to be read.  You can use COM to do so, the [ShellLinkObject class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774004%28VS.85%29.aspx) implements the IShellLink interface.  Get started with Project + Add Reference, Browse tab and navigate to c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll.  That generates an interop library.  Write code like this:

```
public static string GetLnkTarget(string lnkPath) {
    var shl = new Shell32.Shell();         // Move this to class scope
    lnkPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(lnkPath);
    var dir = shl.NameSpace(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(lnkPath));
    var itm = dir.Items().Item(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(lnkPath));
    var lnk = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)itm.GetLink;
    return lnk.Target.Path;
}
```

Comment: Nice snippet.  BTW, when I used this I had to change the last line to return lnk.Target.Path.

Comment: Actually, the last line should be return lnk.Path

Comment: you also have to add Microsoft.Csharp assembly to avoid the Binder compile error, and instead of adding the shell32.dll you should select 'Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation' from the COM Type Libraries tab

Comment: This appears to require an STA thread to run, which you get for free in a C# UI app, but have to create manually in a console app.  Even then, I ran into errors on some machines that appear to relate to permissions to interact with the UI system.  Console apps (including windows services) may not have permission to interact with UI.  The lower-level IShellLink seems to avoid these issues of STA thread and permissions.  See accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139010/how-to-resolve-a-lnk-in-c-sharp

Comment: I'm able to use this to read an .lnk file without utilizing a UI or other thread.

Comment: It is risky, older Windows versions don't behave well when you use this object on a non-STA thread.  Win7 is the new XP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe ReadAllBytes induces the OS to follow the lnk to its target. I suspect, the OS has already resolved the lnk file (maybe when you browsed to the file in Windows Explorer).

Comment: It is a advertised shortcut from another computer, so the link can never be resolved