# c# The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: c#

I have a program that opens a file with this line of code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\RandomUser\Documents\Rainmeter\Todo List.lnk";
p.Start();
```

I am getting an error that "The system cannot find the path specified"
and the path IS valid for sure.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Edit: It works perfectly fine when the file is an exe file.

Comment: Are you sure the name of the file is the same?

Comment: absolutely...I am actually thinking that it could be windows 10 preview related thing

Comment: It seems that .lnk does not open when the path of the exe it points to contains ProgramFiles. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523419/unable-to-launch-shortcut-lnk-files-from-32-bit-c-sharp-application-when-the-f

Comment: Is the app behind the shortcut 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Yeaaah.. Damn it... I guess I will have to create few cmd files to open it for me then

Comment: I am not sure, they are not saying that on their website.

Comment: Is it in programFiles or ProgramFiles(x86)?

Comment: ProgramFiles, my bad

Comment: No, it is 64-bit, so look at the answer for it in the link i provided few comments up.

Comment: problem solved, moved the app in different directory xP

Comment: Please, upvote the question of  the author of the question in the link if it has helped you clarify the problem or the answer if you use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the program couldn't access "Program Files" (that's where the shortcut was leading to), so I reinstalled the app into "Program Files(x86)" and that did the trick.

Comment: This is not an answer, because not everybody will be able to reinstall application just like that. This circumvents the problem, does not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Process p = new Process(); 
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"Todo List.lnk"; 
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\RandomUser\Documents\Rainmeter"; 
p.Start();
```

Lnk is a shortcut, You can use this function to get lnk target path

```
Public Shared Function GetLnkTarget(lnkPath As String) As String
Dim shl = New Shell32.Shell()
' Move this to class scope
lnkPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(lnkPath)
Dim dir = shl.[NameSpace](System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(lnkPath))
Dim itm = dir.Items().Item(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(lnkPath))
Dim lnk = DirectCast(itm.GetLink, Shell32.ShellLinkObject)
Return lnk.Target.Path
```

End Function

Comment: Lnk is a shortcut . When opening this file from explorer it is done? Try replace this path with the shortcut target

Comment: when I enter the path into a cmd prompt, it runs normally.

Comment: Edited my answer. Try to pass the target path

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use either the [start command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx) or `cmd /c` followed by the link as argument.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "start";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"C:\\Users\\RandomUser\\Documents\\Rainmeter\\Todo List.lnk\"";
p.Start();
```

or

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c \"C:\\Users\\RandomUser\\Documents\\Rainmeter\\Todo List.lnk\"";
p.Start();
```

And take care of "long directory names" which need to be enclosed with two " characters.

Comment: It should be correct because you need to enclose the file name with a space in it with " characters.

Comment: the first one doesn't work and the cmd command opens and closes, but nothing happens

Comment: this time I got that the path doesn't exist, but it is there and the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exactly way to fix this problem... But I've tried to another device with path "Program file(x86)" It ran, but with my device with path "Program file" It didn't. If anyone can change path when we code into "Program file(x86)". Reply my comment please!!

Comment: This answer does not seem to answer anything. Please use the comments for that.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30568173)