# Winapi - callback when user prints a file

Tags: c#, c, winapi, printing, hook

the task is to create a log of all .pdf print jobs a user has sent from a specific computer. Once the file gets printed, I want to open the file (programmatically) and extract some information from it.

I know that I can use the [Print Spooler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve a list of all printers and then use [GetJob()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144894%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find information about a new job. The JOB_INFO structure does not contain the full file path, however, which would be what I need to open the file, however. This makes sense since I can also send a print job directly from any program without having any actual file at all.

Is there a way of hooking into the default print dialog? Or maybe the "Print..." - button in the windows explorer? Not really sure where to start looking, I will be glad for any hint I can get.

Ideally in C#, but any language will be fine.

Comment: You probably want to write a [Print Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563806(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with the Print Monitor sounded good, but I've gone another (possibly simpler) way now.

1. Enumerate the new .lnk files in the "Recent" - directory. ([Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))
2. Analyze the filename to check if it is a .pdf file.
3. If so, enumerate the print jobs of all printers to see if there is a job whose filename matches the name of the recently opened file.
4. If there is such a job, [follow the .lnk to the destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660705/how-to-follow-a-lnk-file-programmatically). This is the printed file.

This relies on the fact that a .pdf file has to opened with a PDF viewer before it will be printed. The method requires to check all print jobs and recent files regularily, however, which can be rather performance intensive.

Comment: Recents only has 99 files currently in my windows. What about user opened the file few hours ago and it is not in recents now?