# In File.Exists() how to know if the file is the reall file or a shortcut?

Tags: c#, shortcut

I have a file in the folder like `"c:\a\abc.mdb"`

Sometimes someone could move it to somewhere else and leave a shortcut like `"c:\a\abc.mdb.lnk"`.

In that case when I call `IO.File.Exists(@"c:\a\abc.mdb")` it still return true. In that case how can I verify if the real file exists, or whether the situation is:

- abc.mdb exists only
- abc.mdb.lnk exists only
- or both of them exists?

Comment: I am pretty sure `File.Exists` won't resolve a shortcut. You'll need to find some way to read the shortcut and determine the target.

Comment: I believe the file system (NTFS particularly) is unaware of shortcuts, it's solely the feature of Windows Explorer. The FS is aware of hard/soft links, but it's completely different story.

Comment: Of interest regarding lnk files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660705/how-to-follow-a-lnk-file-programmatically

Comment: This link can be handy: http://www.geektieguy.com/2007/11/19/how-to-parse-special-lnk-files-aka-msi-shortcuts-aka-windows-installer-advertised-shortcuts-using-c/

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9882819/3038677

Comment: I tried this out, but if I have a shortcut at `C:\somefolder\somelink.lnk`, `File.Exists(@"C:\somefolder\somelink")` is still false. Are you sure this works the way you're describing?