# How can I find the destination of a .lnk file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, lnk

I made a explorer.exe clone, with a treeview and a listview etc.

Now I need to handle clicking a .lnk file, so I need the destination path of a .lnk file..

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community!  Please provide some code.  People get pretty vicious around here pretty quickly if you don't.  What have you tried already?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET read binary contents of .lnk file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565885/net-read-binary-contents-of-lnk-file)

Comment: Once again, NOT off topic and not a bad question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try;

```
Public Shared Function GetLnkTarget(lnkPath As String) As String
    Dim shl = New Shell32.Shell()
    ' Move this to class scope
    lnkPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(lnkPath)
    Dim dir = shl.[NameSpace](System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(lnkPath))
    Dim itm = dir.Items().Item(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(lnkPath))
    Dim lnk = DirectCast(itm.GetLink, Shell32.ShellLinkObject)
    Return lnk.Target.Path
End Function
```

You need to reference a COM object; Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [`WshShell Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> You create a WshShell object whenever you want to run a program locally, manipulate the contents of the registry, create a shortcut, or access a system folder.

and use its [`CreateShortcut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method:

> Creates a new shortcut, or opens an existing shortcut.

The resulting [`WshShortcut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6kst2k%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object contains a [`TargetPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/594k4c67%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property, which is what you're looking for.

Example:

```
Dim shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim path  = shell.CreateShortcut(path_to_your_link).TargetPath
```

Comment: This is better answer