# change of location of the database dynamically in app running

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, accessdatasource

Try to make my app read the ms-access database from shortcut of my database it failed to read,  so try to change the location of database dynamically ( there is an option in the app to move the database to drop-box folder and create a shortcut to that database in app folder )

try to make an shortcut to the moved ms-database

the app to read the database or to change the location of database dynamically

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not clear from your question what you are asking. Be sure and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question so we can help you with a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, you should create a folder with a clear name in your VB.Net application path, namely inside the project Debug folder, let's name that folder as "MyProjFiles", so it will be in this path: `ProjectFolderName\bin\Debug\MyProjFiles`
2. Put your whole projects files inside our lovely folder `MyProjFiles`, including all types of your attachments: database, images, sounds, files, etc.
3. Call your database or whatever of those attachments files in addition to our `\MyProjFiles\` using this method: `My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\MyProjFiles\YourFilesPathHere.EXT"`.
4. Now, the whole path will be such as this string: `"C:\CurrentUserNam\RootFolder\ProjectFolderName\bin\Debug\MyProjFiles\YourFilesPathHere.EXT"`

For great practical example of this, supposuply let's  open our `MSAccessDB.accdb` which is already copied into our project folder `\MyProjFiles\` by this code directly:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory() & "\MyProjFiles\MSAccessDB.accdb")
```

The result will be simply opening our database which called "MSAccessDB.accdb"

Or open some pdf files such as this line:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirector() & "\MyProjFiles\MyPdfFile.pdf")
```

and so on.

I hope this can help you all brothers.
Best ^_^ Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this link.
It explains how to read the information you need to give the access Datareader something to do.
[.NET read binary contents of .lnk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565885/net-read-binary-contents-of-lnk-file)

Maybe this is enough, so you don't need to copy anything.