# Get target data of a Windows shortcut via command

Tags: shortcut-file

I have a folder with 16000 files, execpt some of them are shortcuts to files.
Is there a command to extract the path and filename of the linked file, so I know where the physical file is?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565885/net-read-binary-contents-of-lnk-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Unix:`readlink` is a command line tool that you can use, along with the `find`, to extract the path and filename of the linked file.

```
find /path/to/your/folder -type l -exec readlink -f {} \;
```

For windows: you can use the `where` and `wmic` commands in combination

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path\to\your\folder" -Filter *.lnk -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName; (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut($_.FullName).TargetPath }
```