# How can I access the Recent Places list in Windows 7 using C#

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-7

Windows 7 introduced a Recent Places special folder in Explorer which shows you the recently accessed folders.  This folder includes only folders, i.e. it excludes files.

This is different from the `Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent` folder and as far as I can see both [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [KNOWNFOLDER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) don't list a Recent Places folder.

How can I get the contents of the Recent Places special folder using C#?

Comment: Are you refering to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`?

Comment: no, I mean the Recent Places feature in Explorer (normally just below the Desktop button in the top left, under Favorites)

Comment: For some reason I can't see it ;(. Anyway, did you take a look at the path I gave you to see if both places contain the same shortcuts?

Comment: @OscarMederos: maybe. The Recent list contains both files and folders while the Recent Places has only directories but I guess I could manually filter and only get the links to directories. Will try. just thought that there might be a new dedicated special folder.

Comment: It surely is a virtual folder.  Not well supported by .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there doesn't seem to be any direct access to this 'virtual folder' I used a workaround.

```
string[] GetRecentPlaces()
{
    var places = new List<string>();
    foreach (var lnk in Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent), "*.lnk"))
    {
        var path = LinkHelper.ResolveShortcut(lnk);
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            places.Add(path);
        }
    }
    return places.ToArray();
}
```

where `LinkHelper` is taken from this answer: [How to resolve a .lnk in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139010/how-to-resolve-a-lnk-in-c)

EDIT: changed from using file attributes to Directory.Exists as FileAttribute.Directory flag doesn't seem to be always set correctly.