# Getting the full path of a lnk file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, text, text-files, streamwriter

I have a textfile with a content like this:

```
F:\-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Rock\Breaking Benjamin - Fade Away.mp3.lnk
F:\-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Rock\Breaking Benjamin - Lights Out.mp3.lnk
F:\-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Rock\Versaemerge - No Consequences.mp3.lnk
F:\-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Rock\VersaEmerge - Past Praying for.mp3.lnk
F:\-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Rock\Watch Commander - Clock & Compass.mp3.lnk
```

What I need is to get all the real paths of the link files, and store it in a var.

For example, if the textfile contains this line:

```
F:\-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Rock\VersaEmerge - Let Down.mp3.lnk
```

Then i need to get the real location, which is this:

```
F:\Music\Songs\2010\Rock (English)\VersaEmerge - Let Down.mp3
```

I use the next method to get all the ".lnk" files of a folder and then writes the filenames into a text file (the text file that I've mentioned above)

PS: I post this because maybe someone know how to do a trick here for my purposes:

```
   Dim Temp_file As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "\PlayList_temp.m3u"

    Using objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Temp_file, False)
        For Each folder In ArgsArray
            If Not folder = Nothing Then
                Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(folder)
                Dim files As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.lnk")
                Dim file As IO.FileInfo
                For Each file In files
                    objWriter.Write(file.FullName & vbCrLf)
                Next
            End If
        Next
        End Using
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this solution [How to resolve a .lnk in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139010/how-to-resolve-a-lnk-in-c-sharp) which was written in C#.  Here is the solution written in VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim TargetFilename As String = ResolveShortcut("C:\Users\WinUser\Desktop\Test.pdf - Shortcut.lnk")
    End Sub

    <DllImport("shfolder.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Friend Shared Function SHGetFolderPath(hwndOwner As IntPtr, nFolder As Integer, hToken As IntPtr, dwFlags As Integer, lpszPath As StringBuilder) As Integer
    End Function

    <Flags()>
    Private Enum SLGP_FLAGS
        ''' <summary>Retrieves the standard short (8.3 format) file name</summary>
        SLGP_SHORTPATH = &H1
        ''' <summary>Retrieves the Universal Naming Convention (UNC) path name of the file</summary>
        SLGP_UNCPRIORITY = &H2
        ''' <summary>Retrieves the raw path name. A raw path is something that might not exist and may include environment variables that need to be expanded</summary>
        SLGP_RAWPATH = &H4
    End Enum

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Structure WIN32_FIND_DATAW
        Public dwFileAttributes As UInteger
        Public ftCreationTime As Long
        Public ftLastAccessTime As Long
        Public ftLastWriteTime As Long
        Public nFileSizeHigh As UInteger
        Public nFileSizeLow As UInteger
        Public dwReserved0 As UInteger
        Public dwReserved1 As UInteger
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=260)>
        Public cFileName As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=14)>
        Public cAlternateFileName As String
    End Structure

    <Flags()>
    Private Enum SLR_FLAGS
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Do not display a dialog box if the link cannot be resolved. When SLR_NO_UI is set,
        ''' the high-order word of fFlags can be set to a time-out value that specifies the
        ''' maximum amount of time to be spent resolving the link. The function returns if the
        ''' link cannot be resolved within the time-out duration. If the high-order word is set
        ''' to zero, the time-out duration will be set to the default value of 3,000 milliseconds
        ''' (3 seconds). To specify a value, set the high word of fFlags to the desired time-out
        ''' duration, in milliseconds.
        ''' </summary>
        SLR_NO_UI = &H1
        ''' <summary>Obsolete and no longer used</summary>
        SLR_ANY_MATCH = &H2
        ''' <summary>If the link object has changed, update its path and list of identifiers.
        ''' If SLR_UPDATE is set, you do not need to call IPersistFile::IsDirty to determine
        ''' whether or not the link object has changed.</summary>
        SLR_UPDATE = &H4
        ''' <summary>Do not update the link information</summary>
        SLR_NOUPDATE = &H8
        ''' <summary>Do not execute the search heuristics</summary>
        SLR_NOSEARCH = &H10
        ''' <summary>Do not use distributed link tracking</summary>
        SLR_NOTRACK = &H20
        ''' <summary>Disable distributed link tracking. By default, distributed link tracking tracks
        ''' removable media across multiple devices based on the volume name. It also uses the
        ''' Universal Naming Convention (UNC) path to track remote file systems whose drive letter
        ''' has changed. Setting SLR_NOLINKINFO disables both types of tracking.</summary>
        SLR_NOLINKINFO = &H40
        ''' <summary>Call the Microsoft Windows Installer</summary>
        SLR_INVOKE_MSI = &H80
    End Enum

    ''' <summary>The IShellLink interface allows Shell links to be created, modified, and resolved</summary>
    <ComImport(), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")>
    Private Interface IShellLinkW
        ''' <summary>Retrieves the path and file name of a Shell link object</summary>
        Sub GetPath(<Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszFile As StringBuilder, cchMaxPath As Integer, ByRef pfd As WIN32_FIND_DATAW, fFlags As SLGP_FLAGS)
        ''' <summary>Retrieves the list of item identifiers for a Shell link object</summary>
        Sub GetIDList(ByRef ppidl As IntPtr)
        ''' <summary>Sets the pointer to an item identifier list (PIDL) for a Shell link object.</summary>
        Sub SetIDList(pidl As IntPtr)
        ''' <summary>Retrieves the description string for a Shell link object</summary>
        Sub GetDescription(<Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszName As StringBuilder, cchMaxName As Integer)
        ''' <summary>Sets the description for a Shell link object. The description can be any application-defined string</summary>
        Sub SetDescription(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszName As String)
        ''' <summary>Retrieves the name of the working directory for a Shell link object</summary>
        Sub GetWorkingDirectory(<Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszDir As StringBuilder, cchMaxPath As Integer)
        ''' <summary>Sets the name of the working directory for a Shell link object</summary>
        Sub SetWorkingDirectory(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszDir As String)
        ''' <summary>Retrieves the command-line arguments associated with a Shell link object</summary>
        Sub GetArguments(<Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszArgs As StringBuilder, cchMaxPath As Integer)
        ''' <summary>Sets the command-line arguments for a Shell link object</summary>
        Sub SetArguments(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszArgs As String)
        ''' <summary>Retrieves the hot key for a Shell link object</summary>
        Sub GetHotkey(ByRef pwHotkey As Short)
        ''' <summary>Sets a hot key for a Shell link object</summary>
        Sub SetHotkey(wHotkey As Short)
        ''' <summary>Retrieves the show command for a Shell link object</summary>
        Sub GetShowCmd(ByRef piShowCmd As Integer)
        ''' <summary>Sets the show command for a Shell link object. The show command sets the initial show state of the window.</summary>
        Sub SetShowCmd(iShowCmd As Integer)
        ''' <summary>Retrieves the location (path and index) of the icon for a Shell link object</summary>
        Sub GetIconLocation(<Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszIconPath As StringBuilder, cchIconPath As Integer, ByRef piIcon As Integer)
        ''' <summary>Sets the location (path and index) of the icon for a Shell link object</summary>
        Sub SetIconLocation(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszIconPath As String, iIcon As Integer)
        ''' <summary>Sets the relative path to the Shell link object</summary>
        Sub SetRelativePath(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszPathRel As String, dwReserved As Integer)
        ''' <summary>Attempts to find the target of a Shell link, even if it has been moved or renamed</summary>
        Sub Resolve(hwnd As IntPtr, fFlags As SLR_FLAGS)
        ''' <summary>Sets the path and file name of a Shell link object</summary>
        Sub SetPath(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszFile As String)

    End Interface

    <ComImport(), Guid("0000010c-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Public Interface IPersist
        <PreserveSig()>
        Sub GetClassID(ByRef pClassID As Guid)
    End Interface


    <ComImport(), Guid("0000010b-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Public Interface IPersistFile
        Inherits IPersist
        Shadows Sub GetClassID(ByRef pClassID As Guid)
        <PreserveSig()>
        Function IsDirty() As Integer

        <PreserveSig()>
        Sub Load(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszFileName As String, dwMode As UInteger)

        <PreserveSig()>
        Sub Save(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszFileName As String, <[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> fRemember As Boolean)

        <PreserveSig()>
        Sub SaveCompleted(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> pszFileName As String)

        <PreserveSig()>
        Sub GetCurFile(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ppszFileName As String)
    End Interface

    Const STGM_READ As UInteger = 0
    Const MAX_PATH As Integer = 260

    ' CLSID_ShellLink from ShlGuid.h 
    <ComImport(), Guid("00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")> Public Class ShellLink
    End Class


    Public Shared Function ResolveShortcut(filename As String) As String
        Dim link As New ShellLink()
        DirectCast(link, IPersistFile).Load(filename, STGM_READ)
        ' TODO: if I can get hold of the hwnd call resolve first. This handles moved and renamed files.  
        ' ((IShellLinkW)link).Resolve(hwnd, 0) 
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(MAX_PATH)
        Dim data As New WIN32_FIND_DATAW()
        DirectCast(link, IShellLinkW).GetPath(sb, sb.Capacity, data, 0)
        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function

End Class
```